# extjs problem with scroll on grid panel

Tags: extjs, grid, scroll, panel

Hello I got problem with scroll on my grid.
Here is the code (nothing fancy or special in it)

```
Ext.define('grid.list',{
    alias:'widget.grid.list',
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    title: 'list',
    frame:true,
    width:325,
    store: new axs.dry.cargo.data.store.list,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    style:{
        cursor: 'default'
    },
    viewConfig: {
        autoScroll: true
    },
    features:[Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{
        groupHeaderTpl: '{name}'
    })],
    columns: [
    {
        text: 'Name',
        flex: true,
        dataIndex: 'name',
        sortable: false
    }
    ],
    initComponent:function(){
        this.on('beforerender',function(){
            this.store.load();
        });
        grid.list.superclass.initComponent.apply(this,arguments)
    }
})
```

Grid is looking good and the scroller is showing BUT over the scrollbar extjs generates a DIV who is making the real problem. Because of that div I CAN'T click on the scrollbar because the transparent DIV is over it.... here is the code of this useless DIV

```
<div id="gridscroller-1032" class="x-component x-scroller x-scroller-vertical x-component-default x-docked x-docked-right x-component-docked-right x-component-default-docked-right" style="width: 17px; height: 297px; left: 302px; top: 47px; " role="presentation"><div class="x-stretcher" id="ext-gen1392" style="width: 1px; height: 2953px; "></div></div>
```

I hear opinion that this div is generated for "infinitive grid" but ...
Can you help me with good solusion (removing the element by selecting its ID is not a good solusion)

PS. When I remove the fixet width of my grid.list element the problem gone ... but then it starts showing horisontal scroll bar who looks ugly and I can remove it only by setting the width to fixed size.

PS2. I'm using the default css files and no special styles or anything.

Comment: How come you extending a Panel instead of GridPanel here? extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

Comment: I need and I do extend 'Ext.grid.Panel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed by itself. I have integrate my form in the main project and the scrollbar appears...
I don't know why is that happening, maybe it is extjs bug.